# Inconsistent behavior of MSVC vs. GCC with sizeof

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-bug, visual-c++-2015

Consider the following code:

```
#include <cstddef>

class A
{
public:
    struct B
    {
        int M;
    };

    static void StaticFunc();
};

void A::StaticFunc()
{
    const std::size_t s0 = sizeof(::A::B::M);
    const std::size_t s1 = sizeof(A::B::M);
    const std::size_t s2 = sizeof(B::M);
}

int main()
{
    const std::size_t s3 = sizeof(A::B::M);
    return 0;
}
```

[GCC compiles it](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fce3eb4239c17398), just warning about the unused variables.

Visual C++ 2015 however fails to compile it with:

```
error C2326: 'void A::StaticFunc(void)': function cannot access 'A::B::M'
```

on the lines

```
const std::size_t s0 = sizeof(::A::B::M);
const std::size_t s1 = sizeof(A::B::M);
```

in `StaticFunc()`.

The other line `s2 = ...`, and `s3 = ...` in `main()` compile fine.

Is this a bug in MSVC, or do I miss something basic here?

Comment: I see no reason why it shouldn't work. So I would say with some degree of confidence it's a VS bug.

Comment: since these compiler vs compiler questions are popular here, let's open the pools:

Comment: A) it's a VS bug

Comment: B) it's a gcc bug

Comment: C) I don't want to vote, just show me the results

Comment: @bolov We have a winner.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a bug in MSVC.

C++11/14 allows a non-static class member to be used in a non-evaluated context, see 5.1.1  [expr.prim.general] p. 13:

> An id-expression that denotes a non-static data member or non-static member function of a class can only be used:
>
> ...
>
> (13.3) — if that id-expression denotes a non-static data member and it appears in an unevaluated operand.
>
> [ Example:
>
> ```
>     struct S {
>        int m;
>     };
>     int i = sizeof(S::m);        // OK
>     int j = sizeof(S::m + 42);   // OK
> ```
>
> — end example]

Edit: it looks like MSVC accepts `B::M` and doesn't accept `A::B::M`, which is a completely inexplicable behaviour. I don't see how it could be anything but a bug.

clang++ like g++ in C++11 and C++14 mode accepts the program. clang++ in C++03 mode rejects all 4 references to `M` (C++03 doesn't have anything like p. 13.3), whereas g++ in C++03 mode still accepts them (this is probably a g++ C++03 mode bug).